# How can I change text for every page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For each reload I want to change the text How can I do this?
first load want to display "Good Morning" or "Good Night".If at first load it displayd "Good Night" then the next time it must want to display "Good Morning"
By using Math Random its displaying randomly So it display twice or thrice one text and then other So for every page load text want to change

Following is the skeleton of my  code

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var text = ["Good Morning","Good Night"];
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*2));
  $('#myTxt').html(text[x]);

});
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<form>
<div style="border: 1px red solid; height:100px; width:200px;">
   <span id="myTxt"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I recommand to use Google to load your jQuery. Because Google did already cache it for almost all users. Look here for more info http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: You may need to set a cookie (or a local storage value) with the index of the text displayed on last visit. When you know what has been displayed last time you just select the other text now, and also update the cookie value. A short overview using js cookies can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie for count of page reload and can change text for each reload

```
if (getCookies("count")="")
  // first time loaded
   count = 1;
else {
 // get a variable in cookie called count
   count =   getCookies("count");
   count = count +1;
    }
 // and set count again to cookie
  setCookie("count",count );
```

for the getCookie() and setCookie() function u can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: You should change values into count, and %2 count after each increment

Comment: want to include any .js file  jquery.cookie.js file

Comment: @Athi no it's based on core javascript doesn't depend on any js lib

Comment: if (getCookies("count")=="")

Comment: how can I fix count is not defined error?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var rld_cnt=parseInt($.cookie('rld_cnt')||0)+1;
  $.cookie('rld_cnt',rld_cnt);
  var text = ["Good Morning","Good Night"];
  $('#myTxt').html(text[rld_cnt%2]);

});
```

Comment: cookie is not setting for me                                          var rld_cnt=($.cookie('rld_cnt')||0)+1;  alert(rld_cnt); its not giving any alert message

Comment: jquery.cookie.js included? @vijay 's answer easier.

Comment: i included jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js  file then also its not workin

Comment: Eveyone must use the older version of [cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) not new version. The new one is not jQuery plugin and this answer won't work with it. Click [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js) to get the jquery.cookie.js plugin code. That stackoverflow answer helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438540/jquery-cookie-not-a-function