# jQuery "$.cookie" not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I can't figure out why I'm getting this simple error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
```

Here is where I implement JavaScript and jQuery:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="cookies.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/changeTheme.js"></script>
<script>
    function cookieTest() {
        $.cookie("test", "Cookies are working!");
        alert($.cookie("test"));
    };
    cookieTest();
</script>
```

I checked a thousand times, and I don't see a reference typo. I tried this by viewing my site offline as well as online.

I downloaded the cookies plugin from https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie.

Also, alerts work when I do this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="cookies.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/changeTheme.js"></script>
<script>
    function cookieTest() {
        alert("Test");
    };
    cookieTest();
</script>
```

My file is named cookies.js because I simply copied the source code from github and put it in a new js file.
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMD7.png)

Comment: File name is js.cookie.js, check if it is a typo.

Comment: You appear to be using syntax from an older version of cookie.js (from here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) whilst linking to a newer github repo with a version that isn't dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library you're using is not a jquery plugin. Use an older version - 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

As I didn't find any cdn source of this plugin I've copy-pasted it's content and it's working.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wbcq3ho4/

```
<script src="CORRECT LIBRARY PATH HERE"></script>
<script>
    function cookieTest() {
        $.cookie("test", "Cookies are working!");
        alert($.cookie("test"));
    };
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="cookieTest();">
Click me
</button>
```

Just download the file manually or using bower/composer and put the correct link in your html code

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. I wasted my half day to this error

Answer (score 0):

This library is not based on jQuery, make sure you check out how to use it on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
Cookies("yourCookie","yourCookieText");
```